# "tracked up" verbal phrase meaning

Tags: phrases, idioms, phrasal-verbs, phrase-usage, idiom-meaning

I am getting difficulty in deducing the meaning of idiom **tracked up** in the given diction below, 
( paragraph below is taken from the NYTimes editorials ) :

...[the Boston Global](http://www.nytimes.com/2016/02/11/opinion/tracing-the-bishops-culpability-in-the-child-abuse-scandal.html?_r=0) to do more than enumerate the scope of the scandal by reporting on cases involving scores of abusive priests. **The scandal was tracked up the church hierarchy to Cardinal Bernard Law**, who eventually had to resign his leadership when the news media, not the church, documented his role as a protector of abusive priests...

Kindly help me in understanding the meaning of the sentence in bold letters above and the meaning of "tracked something up" idiom metamorphically.

From this link -> http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/track+up
All I understood is, It means spoiling something (maybe a surface) by your dirty feets
How can apply this meaning to above paragraph?

Answer (score 2):

The verb is ***[track](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/track),*** not ***track up.***

> - To follow the tracks of; trail: *tracking game through the forest.*

The meaning is that the scandal lead to the most important people in the church hierarchy ***up to*** Cardinal Bernard Law.

The scandal was tracked, (up the church hierarchy),  to the Cardinal Bernard Law.

Comment: Thanks for the explo..!! :) I got it now. Just one more doubt will the bold sentence implicitly imply that church reputation is affected or spoiled?

Comment: @CoolToshi45 -         I'd say that it does.